# tsplot not plotting (again)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I figured this must be related to the lack of unit / the fact that my units are not continously numbered.

I have a df with batchIDs measured in different years, but many batchIDs only feature in one year, maybe two.

I'd still like to plot the development of the samples across time.

Any ideas how to fix it? The df.to_dict() is [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/ic_fly2/5Lery)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
sns.tsplot(df, time='Year', value='Quality', unit='BatchID', condition='Vegetable')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is problem your time rows are missing.

One possible solution is [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `BatchID` and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by range created with `min` and `max` `Year` and missing values are filled with `ffill` and `bffil` what is same as methods in [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

So from:

```
print (df.head(3))
   BatchID      Farmer  Quality Vegetable  Year
0       31  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato     9
1       31  Pepperidge     0.80    Potato    10
2       95     Johnson     0.50    Carrot     6
```

get this `24` rows:

```
df1 = df.groupby('BatchID')
        .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Year')
                          .reindex(range(df.Year.min(), df.Year.max() + 1)).ffill().bfill())
       .reset_index(level=1)
       .reset_index(drop=True)

print (df1.head(24))
    Year  BatchID      Farmer  Quality Vegetable
0      1     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
1      2     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
2      3     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
3      4     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
4      5     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
5      6     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
6      7     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
7      8     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
8      9     31.0  Pepperidge     0.55    Potato
9     10     31.0  Pepperidge     0.80    Potato
10    11     31.0  Pepperidge     0.80    Potato
11    12     31.0  Pepperidge     0.80    Potato
12     1     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
13     2     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
14     3     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
15     4     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
16     5     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
17     6     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
18     7     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
19     8     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
20     9     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
21    10     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
22    11     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot
23    12     95.0     Johnson     0.50    Carrot


sns.tsplot(df1, time='Year', value='Quality', unit='BatchID', condition='Vegetable')
```

[image: graph]

Comment: That is unfortunately not accurate as I don't have this information, it would distort the results. There are about 300 measurements for each vegetable and year, but the batchIDs are different.

Comment: I am not sure if understand - if missing values in `Year` for some `batchID` then it does not plot. So `tsplot` is impossible use.

Comment: The otherway round not all BatchIDs are present in each year. So if tsplot can't be used, is their onother plot option rather than just finding the means and stds my self and plotting it?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know help you with alternative solutions, because I dont know (seaborn is hard for me) :( But if need help with transforming data some way, it is possible. Only I need know what you need.

Comment: I've made box plots instead, using hue to distinguish the three conditions. Not as nice but works.